# Django - Using signals to make changes to other models

Tags: python, django

say I have two models like so...

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ...
    overall_rating = models.IntegerField()
    ...

class Review(models.Model):
    ...
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='review', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rating = models.IntegerField()
    ...
```

I want to use the ratings from all of the child `Review` objects to build an average `overall_rating` for the parent `Product`. 
**Question:** I'm wondering how I may be able to achieve something like this using Django signals?

I am a bit of a newbie to this part of Django; have never really understood the signals part before.

This `overall_rating` value needs to be stored in the database instead of calculated using a method since I plan on ordering the `Product` objects based on their `overall_rating` which is done on a DB level. The method may look something like this if I were to implement it (just for reference):

```
def overall_rating(self):
    review_count=self.review.count()
        if review_count >= 1:
            ratings=self.review.all().values_list('rating',flat=True)
            rating_sum = 0
            for i in ratings:
                rating_sum += int(i)
            return rating_sum / review_count
        else:
            return 0
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to update your Product after each save of Review. So the best and fastest way would be using post save method. For example, after each saved product you can get all reviews and calculate overall rating and then save it to the Product.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Review, dispatch_uid="update_overall_rating")
def update_rating(sender, instance, **kwargs):
     parent = instance.product
     all_reviews = Review.objects.filter(product=parent)
     parent.overall_rating = get_overall_rating(all_reviews)
```

Comment: Instead of importing the django signal it will be more easy to override the save method of the Review model and do the same thing you suggested!

Comment: Yes you can do that. Save and delete methods should be overwritten when the changes are strictly related to the objects edited. The post_save and pre_save methods are used when you want to make updates to other models. You can use both, but it's about the convention and good practices

Comment: of course ;).. i only wanted to pointing that out! I've upvoted your answer aniway ;)!

Comment: awesome answer, thanks! just wondering, where does the 'get_overall_rating' part come from?

Comment: This is a method you have to create, I`ll leave some fun of coding for you as well :)